# How to remove specific character from string in spark-sql

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I want to convert '123,456' to 123456 (string to int) by spark-sql.

I tried like this.

```
REPLACE('123,456', ',', '')
```

But it didn't work, because spark-sql don't permit REPLACE()

Comment: is there a cast or convert function?

Comment: yes, there is cast function. but, it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`replace` works as expected for me (Spark `2.3.0`):

```
spark.sql("select int(replace('123,456', ',', '')) result").collect()
# [Row(result=123456)]
```

Answer (score 1):

assuming all data are numeric while stored in varchar convert function should solve your issue

```
conv(Column num,
          int fromBase,
          int toBase)
```